# How do I solve integrals over $\mathrm d (\ln x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am trying to solve integrals of the following form:

$$\int_{a}^{\infty}x^b\left[ e^{\frac{x}{500}}-e^{\frac{-x^2}{700}}\right]d\ln x$$

Where $a,b$ are positive real numbers. My main aim is to make this into a form which is easier to numerically integrate, so I think that I need to change variables so that the integral is over a finite region (such as $x\rightarrow \frac{1}{x}$). However, I am not sure at all how to deal with the measure $\mathrm d(\ln x)$. If I change variables using something like $u= \ln x$, then the exponentials end up with exponentials in them again? Which does not help me simplify it at all.

How do I deal with this kind of integral? Should I attempt to remove the $d \ln x$ at all? I have struggled to come up with a suitable change of variables which makes the integral any easier to numerically/analytically solve.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use the fact that $\;d\ln x=\frac{1}{x}dx\;.$

Comment: @Angelo In that case, is it just alright to replace $d ln x$ with  $\frac{1}{x}dx$, and leave the integrand and limits unchanged? (Apologies, I am very rusty.)

Comment: Yes, it is just alright, limits remain unchanged.

Comment: No @Angelo you are wrong we have to change the limits also

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi we don't have to.

Comment: @Novice is right, limits remain unchanged.

Comment: @Novice i understood my mistake

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact which is associated with Stieltjes-Riemann integral i.e.
$$
d\ln x =(\ln x)'dx =\dfrac1x dx.
$$
Then we have
$\int_{a}^{\infty}x^b\left[ e^{\frac{x}{500}}-e^{\frac{-x^2}{700}}\right]d\ln x=\int_{a}^{\infty}\dfrac1x x^b\left[ e^{\frac{x}{500}}-e^{\frac{-x^2}{700}}\right]d x=
\int_{a}^{\infty} x^{b-1}\left[ e^{\frac{x}{500}}-e^{\frac{-x^2}{700}}\right]d x=
\int_{a}^{\infty} x^{b-1} e^{\frac{x}{500}}-\int_{a}^{\infty} x^{b-1}e^{\frac{-x^2}{700}}dx.
$
The result you should obtain thanks to method of integration by parts. Can you end the calculations?

Comment: We do not need to apply the method of integration by parts, indeed the integrand function is positive and divergent to infinity, so the integral is $+\infty\;.$

Comment: @Angelo it was the first what came to my mind. Anyway, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\;d\ln x=\left(\ln x\right)^\prime dx=\frac{1}{x}dx\;,$ we get that

$\int_{a}^{+\infty}x^b\left(e^{\frac{x}{500}}-e^{\frac{-x^2}{700}}\right)d\ln x=\int_{a}^{+\infty}x^{b-1}\left(e^{\frac{x}{500}}-e^{\frac{-x^2}{700}}\right)dx\;.$

Since $\;x^{b-1}\left(e^{\frac{x}{500}}-e^{\frac{-x^2}{700}}\right)>0\;$ for all $\;x>0\;$ and $\;\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} x^{b-1}\left(e^{\frac{x}{500}}-e^{\frac{-x^2}{700}}\right)=+\infty\;,$ it follows that

$\int_{a}^{+\infty}x^{b-1}\left(e^{\frac{x}{500}}-e^{\frac{-x^2}{700}}\right)dx=+\infty\;.$

We do not need to apply the method of integration by parts, indeed the integrand function is positive and divergent to infinity, so the integral is $+\infty\;.$